# Swift: ++ is deprecated - replaced code not working

Tags: ios, swift

I know that "++" will be removed in Swift 3 and it has to be raplaced:

+= 1

but in this code, when I change to this value, I get error:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = images[index++]
    animateImageView()
}
```

When I insert:

```
imageView.image = images[index += 1]
```

I get error. How to change this code? This is image transition code (if I need, I'll pos whole code) and in Simulator everything works, but still, I would like to change it.

Comment: `+=` is called a *compound assignment operator*. And unlike C, it does not return a value. The [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) specifically mentions that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `+= 1` out of the indexer, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = images[index]
    index += 1
    animateImageView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So simple, how didn't I figure it out by my self... :)

This has done the trick.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by dasblinkenlight the solution is to simply move the increment to be after you subscript the array.

Note the reason it is after because that is equivalent to have the postfix increment operator. If you were to use `++index` then you would move the `index += 1` to before the subscript.

A bit of extra info on whats going on here, If you imagine the operators as functions you can see what is going on here.

the `++` operator would have an implementation **like** this:

```
//++ declared as postfix operator before this.
func ++ (inout num: Int) -> Int {
  let temp = num
  num = num + 1
  return temp
}
```

where as the `+=` operator is implemented **like** this:

```
func += (inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int) {
  lhs = lhs + rhs
}
```

The important thing to notice here is that the `++` operator returns an `Int` value that can be used within an subscript where as the `+=` actually returns `void` (or returns nothing) and thus it cannot be used as an `Int` inside the subscript.

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me and explain more. I am new in swift and I am really ready to go all the way. I am practicing every day and love challenges. :)

Must say that I love Swift, and can't wait to learn more of it. Thanks again.